# Given a sequence of random variables $Y_1$, $Y_2$ etc. and $X_n$ defined as $\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k$ with $n>1$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, martingales

Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$ be random variables and set $X_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_k$ $n\ge1$, I should prove that $\sigma\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}=\sigma\{X_1,X_2,...,X_n\}$.

Can you kindly help me to show this? Thank you!

Comment: induction is obviously the way to go

Comment: Or note that $Y$ can be expressed as the successive difference of those $X_i$

Comment: could you be more precise please?

Comment: Can you show one of the inclusions? (The "easier" one?)

Comment: Suggestion: See if you can prove the case where $n=2$.  This may guide you to the general solution.